# need help to create autofill in code igniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, autofill

can anyone to help how create autofill form field in codeigniter 3 with AJAX, i have already browsing but no one success in progress

controller:

```
function autofill(){
        $id_pemesan = $this->input->post('id_pemesan', TRUE);
        $this->mod_marketing->autofill_by_id($id_pemesan,'pemesan');



            $data = array(
            'nama_depan' => nama_depan,
            'nama_belakang' => nama_belakang,
            'alamat' => alamat,
            'provinsi_kota' => provinsi_kota,
            'kode_pos' => kode_pos,
            'email' => email,
            'no_telp' => no_telp
            );

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

model :

```
function autofill_by_id($id_pemesan,$table){

        return $this->db->get_where($table,array('id_pemesan', $id_pemesan));
    }
```

script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
        $("#id_pemesan").change(function(){
            var id_pemesan = $("#id_pemesan").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo site_url('marketing/autofill'); ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    'id_pemesan': id_pemesan
                },
                success: function (pemesan) {
                    $("#nama_depan").val(pemesan.nama_depan);
                    $("#nama_belakang").val(pemesan.nama_belakang);
                    $("#alamat").val(pemesan.alamat);
                    $("#provinsi_kota").val(pemesan.provinsi_kota);
                    $("#kode_pos").val(pemesan.kode_pos);
                    $("#email").val(pemesan.email);
                    $("#no_telp").val(pemesan.no_telp);

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

that my latest try and its still fail

Comment: what was the error so far? what's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change the controller so it checks if response should include data, or error. You actually were not passing the row to the array, so I'm guessing this is what you wanted:

```
function autofill()
{
    $id_pemesan = $this->input->post('id_pemesan', TRUE);
    $row = $this->mod_marketing->autofill_by_id($id_pemesan,'pemesan');

    if( $row )
    {
        $data = array(
            'nama_depan'    => $row->nama_depan,
            'nama_belakang' => $row->nama_belakang,
            'alamat'        => $row->alamat,
            'provinsi_kota' => $row->provinsi_kota,
            'kode_pos'      => $row->kode_pos,
            'email'         => $row->email,
            'no_telp'       => $row->no_telp
        );

        echo json_encode($data);
    }

    // No rows, or there was more than one row
    else
    {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'No rows, or there was more than one row'));
    }
}
```

Change the model to check for row:

```
function autofill_by_id( $id_pemesan, $table )
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where($table,array('id_pemesan', $id_pemesan));

    return $query->num_rows() == 1
        ? $query->row()
        : NULL;
}
```

Modify the JS so you can check for errors:

```
$(function() {
    $("#id_pemesan").change(function(){
        var id_pemesan = $("#id_pemesan").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url('marketing/autofill'); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'id_pemesan': id_pemesan
            },
            success: function (pemesan) {
                if( permesan.error ){
                    alert( permesan.error );
                }else{
                    $("#nama_depan").val(pemesan.nama_depan);
                    $("#nama_belakang").val(pemesan.nama_belakang);
                    $("#alamat").val(pemesan.alamat);
                    $("#provinsi_kota").val(pemesan.provinsi_kota);
                    $("#kode_pos").val(pemesan.kode_pos);
                    $("#email").val(pemesan.email);
                    $("#no_telp").val(pemesan.no_telp);
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('error 2');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i have try your code, its still blank and got alert " no row, or there was more than one row"  or its because version of jquery-ui i use?i use jquery-ui 1.11.4

Comment: Sounds like you've got something else corrupting the response. You need to go to the Net panel of your browser's console and look at the raw response from the server.